# yum complains about no diskspace in a diskless system with initramfs

Tags: linux, yum

I wonder who had such a experience. 
We are using diskless linux servers. Before we use ramdisk, recently we are trying to make a diskless server with ramfs, and we successfully created the rootfs image and booted the server.

Then the issue here is that we can not install anything, because yum complains about no disk space. it is quite true that there is no disk thus no space, but for a ramfs, can we update the linux configuration to by pass this issue?

```
df -kh / 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
-                        0     0     0   -  /
yum install w3m -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Excluding Packages from Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package w3m.x86_64 0:0.5.1-18.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

    ====================================================================================================================
 Package                 Arch                       Version                             Repository              Size
====================================================================================================================
Installing:
 w3m                     x86_64                     0.5.1-18.el5                      os                     1.1 M

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.1 M
Downloading Packages:


Error Downloading Packages:
  w3m-0.5.1-18.el5.x86_64: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/os/packages
    * free   0 
    * needed 1.1 M
```

update:
I checked the yum code, it is using statvfs system call to check the diskspace. So other than creating a "real disk", I have no idea how can I bypass this issue.

Comment: Did you mean to use tmpfs instead?

Comment: yes, initramfs is a kind of tmpfs AFAIK

Comment: initramfs is not tmpfs.

Comment: Aha,  you are right according to this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt. So we are using initramfs.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar use case. I found this [article](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.5.0.0/bk_ambari_troubleshooting/content/ambari-chap5-3-4.html): but for some reason yum continued to check for free disk space before downloading even with

```
diskspacecheck=0
```

I eventually decided to workaround:

```
yum clean all
mount -t tmpfs -o size=5G tmpfs /var/cache/yum
```

Comment: Setting `diskspacecheck=0` and mounting `/var/cache/yum` worked for me. Thanks!